# How to feed frames into motion detector object AForge.net?

Tags: c#, aforge, motion-detection

I'm trying to get a simple motion detection program working using the AForge.net framework. On the AForge website is an example of such a program, but it's quite vague:

```
    // create motion detector
MotionDetector detector = new MotionDetector(
    new SimpleBackgroundModelingDetector( ),
    new MotionAreaHighlighting( ) );

// continuously feed video frames to motion detector
while ( ... )
{
    // process new video frame and check motion level
    if ( detector.ProcessFrame( videoFrame ) > 0.02 )
    {
        // ring alarm or do something else
    }
}
```

I need some help with the condition for the while loop, as I can't find a solution for how to feed video frames into the MotionDetector object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take advantage of AForge's DirectShow VideoInputDevice. And instead of a while loop you will have a NewFrame event to control the motion detector.

First you'll need the references:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Vision.Motion;
using System.Drawing;
```

Next you will need to get your capture device e.g. your webcam and add a new frame event handler to the NewFrame event for the device:

```
Cameras = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
VideoCaptureDevice Camera = new VideoCaptureDevice(Cameras[0].MonikerString);
Camera.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(ProcessNewFrame);
```

Now you can implement the NewFrameEventHandler however you choose:

```
private void ProcessNewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Bitmap frame = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    if (detector.ProcessFrame(frame) > 0.02)
    {
        // ring alarm or do somethng else
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any more assistance. I just completed an AForge based motion tracker project myself.